# LO Calc won't strip quotation marks from text

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, special-characters

Since quotation marks serve a special function, treating them as a character requires workarounds.  There are a number of standard methods, such as doubling the quotation mark or using CHAR(32), its ASCII code.

I needed to strip quotes from around text, and tried every method I could find to represent the quote character in a formula, but nothing worked.  LO Calc displayed the quotation marks, but all attempts to find or compare them in a formula failed to recognize them.

**Diagnostics**

- I thought perhaps that was an item where the Excel methods didn't transfer to LO Calc.  But Googling revealed that is not the case; the same methods should work in Calc.
- I checked to verify the character code for the quotation marks.  The quote symbol typed into Calc was not being stored as character 32, but as character 226.
- It was not a keyboard issue.  Typing a quote mark elsewhere checked out as character 32.
- Character 226 isn't even a left or right quote (characters 147 and 148), it's the code for an accented character not used in English, `â`.
- Since the stored code was for a foreign language character, I verified that all of the language and locale settings were US English (and they were).
- Calc still treats the character as a quote mark for purposes such as designating text.  But it doesn't behave as either a regular character or a quote mark for handling or use in a formula.  It can't be used singly as a character for comparison, and it can't be doubled, either.

I'll post this as a self-answered question in case anyone else runs into the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calc uses smart quotes by default.  It auto-corrects normal quotes to smart quotes.  Both left and right smart quotes are stored as the same character (226).

**Solution**

- From the menu: `Tools | Autocorrect Options`
- Deselect `Replace` for Single Quotes and Double Quotes